# Characterization of monovalued functions

Tags: functions, relations

Let $f$ be a binary relation.

Let $(\bigcap G)\circ f = \bigcap_{g\in G}(g\circ f)$ for every set $G$ of binary relations.

Can we prove that $f$ is monovalued (a function)?

Comment: I did a stupid thing: I got a 100 points bounty for this easy question. I've solved it myself soon after this. For a solution consider $G=\{\{(a;y)\};\{(b;y)\}\}$ for $a\ne b$

Answer (score 0):

I think not. If $f=\varnothing$ (the empty relation), then $f$ is not a function as long as the underlying set is non-empty, but for any other binary relation $g$, one has $g\circ f=\varnothing$.

Comment: $f=\varnothing$ **is** a function. I define function as a monovalued (including zero-valued) binary relation

Comment: @porton Sorry about the misunderstanding. I used the following definition: If $X$ is any set, then a binary relation $f\subseteq X\times X$ is a _function_ if $$\forall x\in X,\,\exists!y\in X:(x,y)\in f.$$ According to this definition, $f=\varnothing$ is _not_ a function as long as $X$ is non-empty. Perhaps you could describe a bit more explicitly what you use as the definition of a function.

Comment: For every $x$ there are no more than one $y$ such that $(x,y)\in f$